# Anyone to know how to redirect to link without delay? reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem when i login using username and password. and when i submit. the page still not changes to /admin/index. but the path link already go to admin/index . for the example http://localhost:3000/ is the login page when i try to login the browser path become http://localhost:3000/admin/index but the page still not changes yet . and i must refresh the page first so the page will changes to dashboard

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';



import "assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css";
import "assets/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "assets/scss/argon-dashboard-react.scss";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import reducer from './actions/reducer'
import LandingLogin from './layouts/LandingLogin.js'
import LandingRegister from './layouts/LandingRegister.js'


const store = createStore(reducer);
const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <Provider store = {store}>
                <Router history={customHistory}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />}  />
                        <Route path="/" render= {() => <LandingLogin/>} />
                        <Route exact path="/register" render= {() => <LandingRegister/>} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

login.js

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// reactstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  FormGroup,
  Form,
  Input,
  InputGroupAddon,
  InputGroupText,
  InputGroup,
  Col
} from "reactstrap";

const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

      let isLogedIn = true
      if (token === null) {
          isLogedIn = false
      }
      this.state = {
          post : [],
          isLogedIn,
          id : '',
          email : '',
          password: '', 
      }

      this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);
      this.submitLogin = this.submitLogin.bind(this);
    }

    getPostAPI = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8001/datauser')
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState ({
              post : res.data
          })
      })
    }

    getPostAPI2 = () => {
      axios.get('http://localhost:8001/dataadmin')
      .then((res) => {
          this.setState ({
              post : res.data
          })
      })
    }

    handleForm  = (e) => { 
      this.setState ({
         [e.target.name] : e.target.value
      })
  }

    submitLogin = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const { post, email, password } = this.state; 
      if(post.find(event =>  `${event.email}${event.password}` === `${email}${password}` )) {
          localStorage.setItem("token","123456781234")
          localStorage.setItem("username",email);
          localStorage.setItem("password",password);
          this.setState ({
            isLogedIn : true
          })          
      } else  {
          alert("Email atau Password Salah!");
          this.setState ({        
              email : '',
              password: ''
          })

      }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
      this.getPostAPI2();
    }

    render() {
      const { email, password } = this.state
      if (this.state.isLogedIn) {
          customHistory.push('/admin/index');
      }
        return (
            <Fragment>
              <Col lg="5" md="7">
                <Card className="bg-secondary shadow border-0">
                  <CardBody className="px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                  <div className="text-center text-muted mb-4">
                      <h2>Form Login</h2>
                  </div>
                    <Form role="form" onSubmit = {this.submitLogin}>
                      <FormGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                            <InputGroupText>
                              <i className="ni ni-email-83" />
                            </InputGroupText>
                          </InputGroupAddon>
                          <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={email} name = "email" placeholder="Email" type="email" required />
                        </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                      <FormGroup>
                        <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                            <InputGroupText>
                              <i className="ni ni-lock-circle-open" />
                            </InputGroupText>
                          </InputGroupAddon>
                          <Input onChange={this.handleForm} value={password} name = "password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required/>
                        </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                      <div className="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
                        <input
                          className="custom-control-input"
                          id=" customCheckLogin"
                          type="checkbox"
                        />
                        <label
                          className="custom-control-label"
                          htmlFor=" customCheckLogin"
                        >
                          <span className="text-muted">Remember me</span>
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div className="text-center">
                        <Button className="my-4" color="primary" type="submit">
                        Log in
                      </Button>
                      </div>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>

            </Fragment>
          );
        }


}


function select(state) {
  return {
     users: state.users
  }
}

export default connect(select)(Login);
```

i expect when login, the page directly change to dashboard without refresh the page. please tell me something  what should i do

Comment: Try to provide `exact` prop to your `Route` with `path="/"`. Another thing is, you want to redirect to `/admin/index` but you don't have matching `Route` instead your will be redirected to `AdminLayout`.

Comment: Are you still using `react-router-dom v3`?

Comment: react router dom v4

Comment: Then why are you using custom browserHistory? You should directly use [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) which automatially uses HTML 5 history API instaed of `Router`

Comment: Your code structure is based on `react-router-dom v3`, you should take some time to read [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) and try to implement `react-router-dom v4`

Comment: before i use createHashHistory but has is the trouble. when i cr8 data . the hash change into the data that i input for the example the # will change into username?=asdqwe?passowrd ?= bla bla bla and slash admin/addadmin. i try to uses browse router but blank page.

Comment: case closed. thank you for giving an attenttion